# pandas.merge inexplicably slow

Tags: python, pandas

The following works great:

```
times1h = pandas.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-01-01', end='2014-01-01', freq='1h')
times10min = pandas.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-01-01', end='2014-01-01', freq='10T')
wind=pandas.DataFrame({'wind':0}, index=times1h)
power=pandas.DataFrame({'power':0}, index=times10min)
%timeit pandas.merge(wind, power, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

100 loops, best of 3: 5.2 ms per loop
```

The following is inexplicably slow. I just make the timestamps of the first dataframe non-unique and have it as a column rather than as an index:

```
times1h = pandas.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-01-01', end='2014-01-01', freq='1h')
times10min = pandas.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-01-01', end='2014-01-01', freq='10T')
wind=pandas.DataFrame({'time':pandas.concat([pandas.Series(times1h),     pandas.Series(times1h)]), 'wind':0})
power=pandas.DataFrame({'power':0}, index=times10min)
%timeit pandas.merge(wind, power, how='inner', left_on='time', right_index=True)

1 loops, best of 3: 16.6 s per loop
```

Why is this so much slower? Can I do anything about this?

I am trying to get a set of (x,y) points for a Power Curve fitting.

I use pandas 0.13.1 because it's the one included in WinPython :)

Comment: you need to show the input frames (or at the very least, df.info())

Comment: Yes, I provided the df.info() etc in my update.
Maybe I need to make a complete example that runs and demonstrates the performance problem

Comment: yes a copy pastable example is best!

Comment: Yeah, okay, I made a more abstract description of the problem - with copy-paste'able code :-)

Comment: This works in 0.14.1 at about the same speed as the top one. Don't exactly recall what the issue was. Upgrading would be your best bet.

Comment: If you're looking for an alternative way to run python on Windows with more up to date packages, Anaconda is a good choice - https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I'll upgrade to 0.14.1 one way or the other. :-)

Comment: First one now runs in 3.3 ms, second one in 120ms. This is really great. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeff posted in the comments under the question, the solution is to upgrade from pandas 0.13.1 to 0.14.1